# rails collection_select error 'undefined method show'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I'm trying to do is create a a drop down list of Demographics.  I'm not really interested in calling the show method, its just a place holder for a method I will write.
The problem I'm having is that, Rails doesn't acknowledge that the show method exists.

demographics view:

```
<%= collection_select( :demographic, :id, @demographics, :demographic, :show) %>
```

demographics_controller:

```
   def show
     @races = Race.all
   end
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are trying to do? You want to list all `races` in the `collection_select`? For which `view` page this code `snippet` belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid ME.
'unknown method' because the method MUST BE IN THE MODEL not the controller.
Whew, I'll never make that mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select), here's the method definition:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Let's say this was a form served by a controller which has declared the `@demographics` instance variable, and you wanted to create `select` and `option` tags with the following structure:

```
<select name="demographic[demographic_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Also, your `@demographics` instance variable has objects which have an `id` and `name` attributes. Then these would be your method parameters:

- object = `:demographic`
- method = `:demographic_id`
- collection = `@demographics`
- value_method = `:id`
- text_method = `:name`

And your `collection_select` would look something like this:

```
collection_select(:demographic, :demographic_id, @demographics, :id, :name)
```

Comment: undefined method `name' for #<Demographic:0x0000000506cde0>